# How i can set setZoomButtonsVisible with aChartEngine?

Tags: achartengine

I created a chart with aChartEngine and it works but when i write

renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

eclipse doesn't acknowledge the method. It appears red.
What is the problem?

thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: What does it say if you hover on the red method? Does it suggest a fix?

Comment: What type is your renderer variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use aChartEngine 1.0, because this helping method is add after acharengine version 0.7.